# Where should things like the current state of an async action be stored in a react-redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a login popup which maps a 'isLoggingIn' boolean to the redux store. When a login request action is dispatched a saga intercepts the action and sends another action that the login is processing, the reducer will take that in and set the 'isLoggingIn' boolean to true.

My store:

```
export interface AppState {
  playerToken:string,  
  loginOpen: boolean,
  loginProcessing: boolean
}
```

The login saga:

```
function* loginUser(action: any) {
  yield put({ type: (LOGIN + PROCESSING) });

  try {
    const response = yield call(apiCall, 'api/token', 'POST', { username: action.payload.username, password: action.payload.password });

   if (response) 
   {
      yield put({ type: (LOGIN + SUCCESS), payload: response.data });
  }
  catch ({ statusCode }) {
    if (statusCode === 401) {
      yield put({ type: (LOGIN + FAIL), payload: { error: "Invalid username or password" } })
    }
    console.log(statusCode);
  }
}
```

Once the saga is done with the login if there's an error it dispatches an action which the reducer sets to a 'loginError' string in the store and sets the isLoggingIn to false, otherwise isLoggingIn is set to false and the user login id is set which prompts the popup to hide itself (i.e. isVisible={this.props.playerToken == undefined).

This seems insanely complicated but I'm not sure how to break this down using Redux principles. I feel strongly the isProcessingLogin should be part of the components state, but the component has no real idea what's going on after it sends the login attempt event and there's no way for it to ever know unless it's listening on for something in the props.

It gets much worse with the various crud operations which need to happen and the various 'isCreatingXModel' booleans which have to be set to true/false in the store and mapped correctly in components.

Is this how redux is supposed to work or am I over using it in places it doesn't belong?

If this is how redux is supposed to be used what are its benefits exactly? I've read online a lot about things which make sense like having a single point of truth, but they can all be done without the crazy redux bloat, I've read people say not to use redux until you need it but that means I'm going to be doing api calls in two conceptually separate areas of code when redux is integrated whenever I 'need it', finally one of the biggest advantages I see purported by advocates is its ability to rewind and move forward in time, which is great but it won't work in any live application which connects to a database in the backend it manipulates unless as part of rewinding there's an undo last api call action.

Comment: For my redux reducers I generally have a state.status string with things like "loading" or "failed" so that I have a clear single entity that is outputting the state of that reducer. It works quite well if your states are easily distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that these are all entirely my opinions.

#### 1. You might not need sagas (or thunk or other 'async' redux plugin)

Remember that redux is state management only. The API calls can be written in vanilla javascript with or without redux. For example: here's a basic replication of your flow without sagas:

e.g.

```
import { setLoadingStatus } from './actions'
import { store } from './reducers' // this is what is returned by a createStore call

export function myApiCall(myUrl, fetchOptions) {
  store.dispatch(setLoadingStatus('loading'))

  return fetch(myUrl, fetchOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      store.dispatch(setLoadingStatus('succeeded', data))
      // do stuff with response data (maybe dispatch a different action to use it?)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      store.dispatch(setLoadingStatus('failed', error))
      // do stuff 
    })
}
```

*Note the use of `store.dispatch`. There's an interesting notion in React-Redux that you can only dispatch actions with mapDispatchToProps, but fortunately, that's not true.*

I replaced your multiple actions with one that takes a state and optional data. This'll reduce the number of actions and reducers you need to write, but your action history will be harder to read. (Instead of three distinct actions, you'll only have one.)

#### 2. You might not need redux.

The example function above could look basically identical if you weren't using redux -- imagine replacing the `store.dispatch` calls with `this.setState` calls. In the future, when you added it, you'd still have to write all the reducer, action, action creator boilerplate, but it would be only slightly more painful than doing it from the start.

As I said above, I usually go with Redux when working with React the built-in state management is has a bad mental map with any sort of large app.

There are two opposing rules of thumb:

1. use redux for state that needs to be **shared between components**
2. use redux for all state and get a **single source of truth**

I tend to lean to the second one. I hate hunting down errant pieces of state in the leaves of a large React component tree. This is definitely a question with no "correct" answer.